# How to create a Multimap<K,V> from a Map<K, Collection<V>>?

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I didn't find such a multimap construction... When I want to do this, I iterate over the map, and populate the multimap. Is there an other way?

```
final Map<String, Collection<String>> map = ImmutableMap.<String, Collection<String>>of(
            "1", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "c"));
System.out.println(Multimaps.forMap(map));

final Multimap<String, String> expected = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    expected.putAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(expected);
```

The first result is `{1=[[a, b, c, c]]}` but I expect `{1=[a, b, c, c]}`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> map = ...;
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Then I believe this is the best you can do

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
  multimap.putAll(key, map.get(key));
}
```

or the more optimal, but harder to read

```
for (Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  multimap.putAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did !
Be just warned, as Kevin pointed it here http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/255cabbcc70925b3 a Multimap is a Map, and then if in the original Map, you have an empty iterable as value, then, the entry "<key, EMPTY_LIST>" will not be added the the multimap

Comment: The miultimap create was util for me: Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create(); It is applicable to all Multimap know implemented classes.

Answer (score 10):

This question is a little old, but I thought I'd give an updated answer. With Java 8 you could do something along the lines of

```
ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
Map<String, Collection<String>> map = ImmutableMap.of(
                           "1", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "c"));
map.forEach(multimap::putAll);
System.out.println(multimap);
```

This should give you `{1=[a, b, c, c]}`, as desired.

Comment: I left java world for quite a while now, but it's always good to stay in touch with the new syntax. It removes some noise, I like it. Thank your for the update. Maybe @kevin-bourrillion could update his answer with this syntax

Answer (score 8):

Here is a useful generic version that I wrote for my [StuffGuavaIsMissing](http://pastebin.com/wFmbw5FE) class.

```
/**
 * Creates a Guava multimap using the input map.
 */
public static <K, V> Multimap<K, V> createMultiMap(Map<K, ? extends Iterable<V>> input) {
  Multimap<K, V> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
  for (Map.Entry<K, ? extends Iterable<V>> entry : input.entrySet()) {
    multimap.putAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
  return multimap;
}
```

And an immutable version:

```
/**
 * Creates an Immutable Guava multimap using the input map.
 */
public static <K, V> ImmutableMultimap<K, V> createImmutableMultiMap(Map<K, ? extends Iterable<V>> input) {
  ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, V> builder = ImmutableMultimap.builder();
  for (Map.Entry<K, ? extends Iterable<V>> entry : input.entrySet()) {
    builder.putAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
  return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: These are somewhat inflexible in that they force you into using a particular Multimap implementation.

Comment: @Michael Hmm I couldn't imagine many things *less* inflexible than a free open-source code snippet posted on the internet :)

Comment: @DanielAlexiuc Hehe. That's not the kind of inflexibility I meant though. If you used the first function throughout your code then subsequently needed to change the type of `Multimap` returned in half of those cases, you're in for a bit of a maintenance nightmare. It's a better design to pass a `Multimap` in via a parameter, I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: For what you're asking, I think you're going to need to fall back to [`Multimap.putAll`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#putAll(K,%20java.lang.Iterable)).

Comment: Thanks, but when I asked the question, I've already tried some functions of this class...and other ways... but the ONLY things which works for me is to iterate over the map...

Comment: @Sylvian: since you marked this answer accepted, does it mean that your problem is now actually solved? It look like not since you didn't mention that in any way. Just wondering, it would otherwise have been a waste of time for others to post a more detailed/suitable answer.

Comment: What about `Multimaps.newMultimap(map, new Supplier<List<String>>(){ public List<String> get() { return new ArrayList<String>();}});`

Comment: It does'nt work since Multimaps.newMultimap() required an empty map as first argument

Comment: @Sylvain, ah OK I misunderstood the behaviour of that method.

Comment: Mark - this doesn't do what you think. It only creates a new multimap based on the underlying maop instance. It expects map to be empty, and throws an exception otherwise

Comment: @Mark Peters Yeah, the Javadoc on that suite of methods could use some help. That requirement should be on the param docs, not just in the exception docs.

Comment: @Hank: that's what I also think, but before asking for an improvement or something like that, I would ask the question here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.flatteningToMultimap` as your stream collector. 
 
Given map:

```java
Map<Integer, Collection<String>> map = Map.of(
   1, List.of("a", "b", "c"),
   2, List.of("d", "e", "f"));
```

You can do the following:

```java
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(flatteningToMultimap(Map.Entry::getKey, it -> it.getValue().stream(), HashMultimap::create));
```

Answer (score 1):

Following  code without Google's Guava library. It is used for double value as key and sorted order

```
Map<Double,List<Object>> multiMap = new TreeMap<Double,List<Object>>();

for( int i= 0;i<15;i++)
{
    List<Object> myClassList = multiMap.get((double)i);
    if(myClassList == null)
    {
        myClassList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        multiMap.put((double) i,myClassList);
    }
    myClassList.add("Value "+ i);
}

List<Object> myClassList = multiMap.get((double)0);
if(myClassList == null)
{
    myClassList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    multiMap.put( (double) 0,myClassList);
}
myClassList.add("Value Duplicate");
for (Map.Entry entry : multiMap.entrySet()) 
{
  System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " +entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedListMultimap<String, String> mm = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        () -> LinkedListMultimap.create(map.size()),
        (m, e) -> m.putAll(e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
        (m1, m2) -> m1.putAll(m2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another method one can use:
[`Multimaps#newMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newMultimap(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier))

If you are using a collection extending `List` or `Set`, the docs recommend using the special methods [`Multimaps#newListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newListMultimap(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier)) and [`Multimaps#newSetMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newSetMultimap(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier)).

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Multimaps;

Multimaps.newListMultimap(myMap, ArrayList::new);
Multimaps.newSetMultimap(myMap, HashSet::new);
```

Comment: Please note that `myMap` needs to be empty, otherwise it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. The Javadoc for the method states: 

> the multimap assumes complete ownership over of map and the lists returned by factory. Those objects should not be manually updated, **they should be empty when provided**...