# Regarding calculating the size of list which is internally is a value of Map

Tags: java

I have query I have a Map which consist of key and valuses will be of type list

```
Map<String, List<String>> ppvValidatedinfo = new Map<String, List<String>>
```

Now I am adding some data into the map initially

```
 1234 , 456987
```

but next time when data added to map it becomes like this

```
1234 , [456987,125789]
```

As shown above that 1234 is key and 456987,125789 are the values internally maintened 
  in list and are the values of the map

Now my query is that I have to go in flow where list size increases more than 1 please advise   how can i track the size of the list , I want to track the size of the list which is a value of map

Comment: `ppvValidatedinfo.get(1234).size()`? Also, do you want to use [`multimap`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093863/how-to-create-a-multimapk-v-from-a-mapk-collection)

Comment: @KarthikT The key is a String. `ppvValidatedinfo.get("1234").size()`

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati ah yes ofcourse.. too late to fix though

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are doing insert, add a check after inserting to see if list size becomes greater than one. e.g.

```
public void add(String key,String value){
ppvValidatedinfo.get(key).add(value);
if(ppvValidatedinfo.get(key).size()>1){
//size is greater than 1 
doProcessing();
}
}
```