# java hashMap<Integer,String> collision

Tags: java, hashmap, hash-collision

I'm sorry if this question was already asked, but i don't fine an answer to my question.
I'm working on HashMap i put two values (7,"value test 1") (7,"value test 2)
According to the specification java API [HashMap put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) the first values is replaced by the second .

My question is when comes the resolution of collision ? why my second value is not store in linkedList or store in another place in the hashMap ? Is it due to the equals or hascode method ??

Best Regards

Comment: If you want to store multiple values for a same key, you can use MultiMap from apache collections. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

Comment: Just in case you didnt know, `Map#put` returns the old value in such a case so you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with hash collision. Hash collisions (ie., keys with the same `hashcode()`) are handled correctly by the HashMap. In your example, both keys are equal (ie., `7.equals(7) == true`), so the old value is replaced.

In the following example

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(7, "value 1");
map.put(7, "value 2");
System.out.println(map.get(7));
```

what would you expect in the last line to happen?

Maybe you are looking for a multimap?

- [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)
- [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093863/how-to-create-a-multimapk-v-from-a-mapk-collectionv)

Comment: that's the strutures i was looking for !! Maybe a silly question lol .. i was expected that the call to get method ont this index return an object LinkedList or something like that ... Why Java dev have choosen this implementation ?

Comment: Because that's what a Map does. It maps one integer to one string (in this case). Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28mathematics%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28computer_science%29. Why the JDK doesn't ship a MultiMap, too, is a good question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Collision handling takes place if two *different* keys resolve to the *same* bucket in the hashmap. In that case the second entry would be put into the linked list.

In your case you replace the entry for the *same* key (7) and thus there is no collision.

If you need a map that contains multiple values per key either use a `Map<key, Set<value>>` (you can also use a `List` etc. instead of a `Set`) and handle adding/removing to that set yourself or use Apache Commons' `MultiMap` or Google Guava's `Multimap`, e.g. `HashMultimap`.

Comment: I just realized what you were saying... too early in the morning for SO... Retracting my -1 and my comment.