# Convert Map<String, Set<String>> to SetMultiMap

Tags: java, guava

I have a `Map <String, Set<String>>`. I am trying to convert it to a `SetMultiMap<String, String>`. Is that conversion possible since Guava doesn't seem to like converting a Map to a SetMultiMap?

Comment: It's a simple enough using a loop or two. Are you asking if there's a shortcut?

Comment: Yeah. I looked at a previous example. 

Multimaps.newMultimap(map, ArrayList::new). Seems like pretty straight forward. I was wondering since Set is an abstract, can we not do it the above way?

Comment: You could use something like `Multimaps.newSetMultimap(new HashMap<>(), HashSet::new)`, but it won't help for your purpose, since the map must be empty. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093863/how-to-create-a-multimapk-v-from-a-mapk-collectionv#comment3172265_3093893).

Comment: You will have to explicitly loop through and copy.   Guava does not provide any other way.